# How share internet (linux)?

Tags: linux, networking, gentoo

How route (masquerade) internet on Sabayon 7 (Gentoo base distro)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can find some good info on people trying to do the exact same thing on Gentoo. (Didn't look for Sabayon in particular, as I suspect the user base of Gentoo to be bigger and the OS itself to be better documented.)

[Here's a script](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-136667.html#136667) someone uses to set up his masquerade. You'll possibly need to modify some parameters. Be careful, you might want to backup your iptables too before doing this!

On Gentoo-wiki, you can find instructions to apparently ["Masquerade the Gentoo Way"](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_setup_a_home-server#Running_Your_Firewall.2FMasquerade_Rules_.22The_Gentoo_Way.22). Certainly worth a read.